# Firebase setPersistenceEnabled in JS/TS in Cordova app

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova/Android/Firebase app and want to use `setPersistenceEnabled` for better offline support. However, I notice that the [relevant FB documentation page for JS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities) omits any mention of `setPersistenceEnabled` (although it's there on the [Android page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities), and it is not present in the typings file.

When researching this problem I ran across the [Cordova plug-in for Firebase](https://github.com/jsayol/cordova-plugin-firebase-sdk), which does show an example of using `setPersistenceEnabled`. However, up to now I have been using Firebase database just fine in my app without this plugin. What additional functionality does this plug-in provide, and how is using it different from using Firebase database calls "natively" from my Cordova app? If I decide to use this plug-in in order to gain access to `setPersistenceEnabled`, will there be any problem if I continue to use the JavaScript SDK elsewhere as I am now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of the Cordova plugin you referenced. It basically allows to use the native SDK on a Cordova app instead of using the JavaScript SDK. That being said, I strongly suggest NOT to use it since it was mostly just an experiment and it's definitely not ready for production, plus it only supports Android at the moment.

On the other hand, there's currently an ongoing effort to add persistence support to the JavaScript SDK which will make the plugin unnecessary anyway. I'm not sure when (or if) that feature will be added to the SDK but you can keep track of the progress on this Github issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/17